# Use different message container style for different chat messages react native

Tags: react-native

I am creating a chat app in react native with react-native-gifted-chat UI. I want to use transparent background for offline messages and solid background for online messages.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to customize your message bubble, you can use the props renderBubble.

To specify the message is online or offline, you can define a new message object call "messageType" like below

```
{
    _id: 1,
    text: "Hello",
    createdAt: new Date(),
    isSent: true,
    isReceived: true,
    user: {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Davis",
    messageType: "online"
}
```

Then you can check the type in you renderBubble.

```
const renderBubble = (props) => {
    if (props.currentMessage.messageType == "online") {
        // your online bubble
    } else {
        // your offline bubble
    }
}
```